# How to print only predefined sequence in perl

Tags: perl, bioinformatics

I am trying to print only predefined sequence (ATOM Name) but not getting expected output. I want to print input file as per following expected output. Chain ID may be A to H.

Code:

```
my $OutputDir = 'C:\test_result_file';
open my $dir, "Document1.txt" or die "Failed to open Document1.txt:$!";
chomp(my @files = <$dir>);

foreach my $file (@files) {
my $win_len = 4;
my @window = ();
my $prev_chain = "";

open my $input, $file or die "failed to open $file: $!\n";
open my $output, '>', "$OutputDir/$file" or die "failed to open $OutputDir/$file.pdb: $!\n";
while (<$input>) {
    my ($atom_name, $chain) = (split)[2, 4];
    next unless $atom_name =~ /\b(?:C4B|O4B|C1B|C2B|O4B|C1B|C2B|C3B|C1B|C2B|C3B|C4B|C2B|C3B|C4B|O4B|C3B|C4B|O4B|C1B)\b/;
    if ($chain eq $prev_chain) {
        if (@window == $win_len) {
            print_window($output, @window);
            shift @window;
        }
        push @window, $_;
    } else {
        print_window($output, @window) if @window;
        @window = ($_);
        $prev_chain = $chain;
    }
}
print_window($output, @window) if @window;

}

sub print_window {
my $fh = shift;
print $fh $_ foreach @_;
print $fh "\n";
}
```

Input File:

```
HETATM10910  C4B NAD A 363      60.856 -58.575 149.282  1.00 40.44           C  
HETATM10911  O4B NAD A 363      61.320 -59.488 148.275  1.00 43.48           O  
HETATM10912  C3B NAD A 363      60.243 -57.426 148.473  1.00 40.37           C  
HETATM10914  C2B NAD A 363      60.167 -57.970 147.054  1.00 40.90           C  
HETATM10916  C1B NAD A 363      61.394 -58.766 147.056  1.00 43.29           C  
HETATM10954  C4B NAD B 363      41.496 -54.407 140.932  1.00 39.26           C  
HETATM10955  O4B NAD B 363      41.936 -54.715 139.568  1.00 41.96           O  
HETATM10956  C3B NAD B 363      42.061 -55.476 141.894  1.00 37.13           C  
HETATM10958  C2B NAD B 363      42.883 -56.336 140.942  1.00 38.13           C  
HETATM10960  C1B NAD B 363      42.233 -56.127 139.593  1.00 42.92           C
```

Expected Output:

A chain:

```
HETATM10910  C4B NAD A 363      60.856 -58.575 149.282  1.00 40.44           C  
HETATM10911  O4B NAD A 363      61.320 -59.488 148.275  1.00 43.48           O  
HETATM10916  C1B NAD A 363      61.394 -58.766 147.056  1.00 43.29           C  
HETATM10914  C2B NAD A 363      60.167 -57.970 147.054  1.00 40.90           C 

HETATM10911  O4B NAD A 363      61.320 -59.488 148.275  1.00 43.48           O  
HETATM10916  C1B NAD A 363      61.394 -58.766 147.056  1.00 43.29           C  
HETATM10914  C2B NAD A 363      60.167 -57.970 147.054  1.00 40.90           C 
HETATM10912  C3B NAD A 363      60.243 -57.426 148.473  1.00 40.37           C   

HETATM10916  C1B NAD A 363      61.394 -58.766 147.056  1.00 43.29           C  
HETATM10914  C2B NAD A 363      60.167 -57.970 147.054  1.00 40.90           C 
HETATM10912  C3B NAD A 363      60.243 -57.426 148.473  1.00 40.37           C   
HETATM10910  C4B NAD A 363      60.856 -58.575 149.282  1.00 40.44           C 

HETATM10914  C2B NAD A 363      60.167 -57.970 147.054  1.00 40.90           C 
HETATM10912  C3B NAD A 363      60.243 -57.426 148.473  1.00 40.37           C   
HETATM10910  C4B NAD A 363      60.856 -58.575 149.282  1.00 40.44           C 
HETATM10911  O4B NAD A 363      61.320 -59.488 148.275  1.00 43.48           O  

HETATM10912  C3B NAD A 363      60.243 -57.426 148.473  1.00 40.37           C   
HETATM10910  C4B NAD A 363      60.856 -58.575 149.282  1.00 40.44           C 
HETATM10911  O4B NAD A 363      61.320 -59.488 148.275  1.00 43.48           O
HETATM10916  C1B NAD A 363      61.394 -58.766 147.056  1.00 43.29           C
```

B chain:

```
HETATM10954  C4B NAD B 363      41.496 -54.407 140.932  1.00 39.26           C  
HETATM10955  O4B NAD B 363      41.936 -54.715 139.568  1.00 41.96           O    
HETATM10960  C1B NAD B 363      42.233 -56.127 139.593  1.00 42.92           C 
HETATM10958  C2B NAD B 363      42.883 -56.336 140.942  1.00 38.13           C

HETATM10955  O4B NAD B 363      41.936 -54.715 139.568  1.00 41.96           O    
HETATM10960  C1B NAD B 363      42.233 -56.127 139.593  1.00 42.92           C 
HETATM10958  C2B NAD B 363      42.883 -56.336 140.942  1.00 38.13           C
HETATM10956  C3B NAD B 363      42.061 -55.476 141.894  1.00 37.13           C  

HETATM10960  C1B NAD B 363      42.233 -56.127 139.593  1.00 42.92           C 
HETATM10958  C2B NAD B 363      42.883 -56.336 140.942  1.00 38.13           C
HETATM10956  C3B NAD B 363      42.061 -55.476 141.894  1.00 37.13           C  
HETATM10954  C4B NAD B 363      41.496 -54.407 140.932  1.00 39.26           C  

HETATM10958  C2B NAD B 363      42.883 -56.336 140.942  1.00 38.13           C
HETATM10956  C3B NAD B 363      42.061 -55.476 141.894  1.00 37.13           C  
HETATM10954  C4B NAD B 363      41.496 -54.407 140.932  1.00 39.26           C  
HETATM10955  O4B NAD B 363      41.936 -54.715 139.568  1.00 41.96           O    

HETATM10956  C3B NAD B 363      42.061 -55.476 141.894  1.00 37.13           C  
HETATM10954  C4B NAD B 363      41.496 -54.407 140.932  1.00 39.26           C  
HETATM10955  O4B NAD B 363      41.936 -54.715 139.568  1.00 41.96           O    
HETATM10960  C1B NAD B 363      42.233 -56.127 139.593  1.00 42.92           C
```

Description: I want to sort HETATM predefined ATOM name (e.g.: C4B, O4B, C1B, C2B etc.). I have above script so far.  So please anyone help me to solve this problem. In my current script I am getting same format but not able to get expected result.

I don't want separate file for A chain and B chain or any chain id. I want to sort ATOM name as per my sequence (Predefined).

My sequence is:

```
C4B-O4B-C1B-C2B
O4B-C1B-C2B-C3B
C1B-C2B-C3B-C4B
C2B-C3B-C4B-O4B
C3B-C4B-O4B-C1B

e.g., first row: C4B
HETATM10910  C4B NAD A 363      60.856 -58.575 149.282  1.00 40.44           C  

Second row: O4B
HETATM10911  O4B NAD A 363      61.320 -59.488 148.275  1.00 43.48           O  
Third Row: C1B
HETATM10916  C1B NAD A 363      61.394 -58.766 147.056  1.00 43.29           C
Fourth Row: C2B  
HETATM10914  C2B NAD A 363      60.167 -57.970 147.054  1.00 40.90           C 
Fifth Row: O4B
HETATM10911  O4B NAD A 363      61.320 -59.488 148.275  1.00 43.48           O 
Sixth Row: C1B
HETATM10916  C1B NAD A 363      61.394 -58.766 147.056  1.00 43.29           C  
Seventh Row: C2B
HETATM10914  C2B NAD A 363      60.167 -57.970 147.054  1.00 40.90           C 
Eighth Row: C3B
HETATM10912  C3B NAD A 363      60.243 -57.426 148.473  1.00 40.37           C   
.
.
.
so on
```

same format for B and other chain also.

Its means I need each row multiple times. all off above atom name should be there in input file and chain wise. we need to copy all of above atom name file and then we need to paste as per above sequence.

Comment: How do you get from five lines that have `A` in the fourth field in the input to 20 lines in the output?

Comment: Just giving us input and output is not enough. You need to describe the transformation in words that a non-expert in the field can understand.

Comment: @simbabque and Dave Cross, I have edited my question, I want to find random atom name, can anyone please help?

Comment: It's still not clear.  So you want to split the input over two files, one for "A" and one for "B", and to sort by the second field?  Sort how?  For me your output doesn't clearly show the sort criterion.  Please explain.

Comment: @zdim, I have edited my question again, I hope you will understand.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your error comes from this line:

```
my ($atom_name, $chain) = (split)[2, 4];
```

This will put the 3rd column in `$atom_name` and the 5th one in `$chain`.

I guess you want:

```
my ($atom_name, $chain) = (split)[1, 3];
```

For the first line you'll get:

`$atom_name = C4B` and `$chain = B`

Comment: @thanks, how to predefined sequence? C4B-O4B-C1B-C2B

Comment: @Vish: push line  that contains `C4B` in `array[0]`, `O4B` in `array[1]` and so on (in your case in `@window`)

Comment: I have tried to defined sequence but I am unable, can you please edit my script? have 3000 file for analysis, please help